# How to compress images without losing quality

Tags: compression

I'm looking for a way to compress images in bulk without losing quality to improve the website loading speed.
I'm working with *surprisegenie.com*
and as it's a unique gifting platform so have so many images on it. Upon checking website health many reports pointing on the image size issue which causing time in loading pages.

So, what we can do to compress images without losing quality?

Answer (score 5):

The very powerful command line utility `convert` allows extremely high quality bulk image processing.

Your only option to compress images **without loosing any quality** is keeping the image intact, and compress it using lossless compression.

However, that may not be what you are after. You refer to a website, and a concern of quick loading. If you want to address that issue, you probably **will need to accept loosing some quality**. There is limited scope to reduce image file size without loosing quality.There is huge scope to reduce image file size for websites without loosing *perceptial* quality, i.e., without noticing the loss in quality compared to showing the original image on the same website.

If, unless what you ask, the above has persuaded you that you are prepared to "loose some quality" nevertheless, then

1. Reduce the resolution of the image to match the resolution of a computer screen.
2. Use lossy jpeg compression. Tune the compression to achieve maximum compression without introducing unacceptable quality loss.

Depending on the original resolution of your graphics, that may reduce the file size to a tiny fraction of the original, without anyone noticing on the website except for the immediate loading.

`convert` is perfectly suited for these tasks, and can be automated for bulk processing.

Comment: Agreed   with the above points , additionally convert your jpeg images to progressive,  which will load images much faster and improves the website's performance

Answer (score 0):

save/ export/ compress image in to *.png. This is lossless format. You can use [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/), [Rawtherapee](https://rawtherapee.com/) or other available software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Curtail](https://github.com/Huluti/Curtail) to compress images offline. You can select the level of compression, and also bulk compress images.

[image]

It can be installed via flatpak or PPA.

### PPA

Enter the following commands to add the PPA to your system. It supports Ubuntu 18.04 and later versions.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/curtail
sudo apt update
sudo apt install curtail
```

### Flatpak

```
flatpak install flathub com.github.huluti.Curtail
```

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I am not the author of this app, but I maintain the PPA.</sup>